# Icecast live stream extract none silent parts into individual files

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg, record, icecast

I am looking to split an icecast audio live stream into individual audio files separated by silences. I was able to achieve this with FFMPEG when having the source input file saved locally first. I can't do that because I have 20 streams being monitored and the original files keeps growing and end up taking too much space on my drive.

Is it possible to do this directly with a live stream audio without saving the full original uncut stream file to drive?

Comment: Have you tried `ffmpeg -i <icecast_url>`?

Comment: this is what I previously used to save the stream locally. I just want to process it live and only save files of activity, no silence.

Comment: You say in the question that you were able to do this with FFmpeg previously... I'm suggesting to you that rather than saving the file locally and then processing with FFmpeg, just set the input to the URL of the stream.